# SQL Server 2008 custom query execution?

Tags: sql-server-2008, key

Without getting into the details, I have a very ugly SQL Server 2008 database that is used by a very ugly piece of software developed by a 3rd party vendor. Through the software interface it allows me to design and build the SQL Server tables and write queries. Great for business users, awful for performance and database design.

None of the tables have primary key columns or indexes and the 'keys' the software generates - as well as pretty much every other important field - are all large `varchars` and `text` columns. In short, performance is awful and I'm being forced to import upwards of 100,000 rows of data and possibly much more.

My question - since I can't control the software or its queries, perhaps I could tweak the way SQL Server processes those queries? Is there a way to modify the query engine or insert a pre-select trigger to map the text-based key to my own created column which I could properly index? In a perfect would I could simply replace any instance of `ColumnA` (for example) in a `WHERE` clause with `ColumnAIndexed` before SQL Server attempts to process it. Any chance something like that is possible?

Thanks.

Comment: No, you cannot tweak SQL Server's query processor in that manner. The only thing I see that you might be able to do is proper indexing on those ugly `varchar` columns that are frequently used in `WHERE` clauses - and adding a proper primary/clustering key (`INT IDENTITY`) would also help, since clustered tables are generally faster than crappy heaps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can't place indexes on the table yourself. If that's the case then you can use an [indexed view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181151.aspx). If you're using SQL Server Enterprise or higher you might not have to do anything.

You can put non-clustered indexes on your own fields (computed in the view) after creating the clustered index.

> Indexed views can be created in any edition of SQL Server. In SQL Server Enterprise, the query optimizer automatically considers the indexed view.

Then it's a matter of querying the view (with `NOEXPAND` if you're not on Enterprise).

Further: look at the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) which demonstrates that the Query Optimizer can consider indexed views on queries that don't reference them. You might be able to design an indexed view around predicates that are commonly used and gain some performance.

Comment: Indexed views are a good idea, I'll have to do some testing to see their impact. Since the software is doing searches on text columns though the view is still going to use that column, right? Could I alias my indexed column in the view with the name of the non-indexed text column? For example, if ColumnA is text and I create ColumnAIndexed, in my view definition could I alias ColumnAIndexed as ColumnA and trick SQL into using that instead?